Why is my API retrieving data from the database faster than from Redis?
I'm working with Django and GraphQL to create a backend for an e-commerce application. Initially, the API for retrieving products was slow, so I decided to implement a Redis stack to speed it up. However, I found that retrieving data from Redis is much slower than retrieving it from the database. Below are the details of my implementation:
Database Query:
def resolve_products(self, info, **kwargs):
    (filter_objects, method_filter, seller_lst, name, ar_name) = (
        product_obj.call_filter_product()
    )
    kwargs["seller_list"] = eller_lst
    query = (
        Products.objects.filter(filter_objects, method_filter, active=True)
        .filter(variants__seller__id__in=list(seller_lst))
        .distinct()
    )
    query = query.filter(
        Exists(
            Variant.objects.filter(
                product_id=OuterRef("id"),
                seller_id__in=seller_lst,
                stock_available=True,
            )
        )
    )

    start_index = int(offset)
    end_index = start_index + int(kwargs.get("first"))
    query_set = query[start_index:end_index]
    final_qs = query_set.annotate(
        stock_available=Exists(
            Variant.objects.filter(
                product_id=OuterRef("id"),
                seller_id__in=seller_lst,
                stock_available=True,
            )
        )
    )

    # Determine hasNextPage
    has_next_page = end_index < len(query)
    connection = ProductsConnection(
        edges=[ProductsConnection.Edge(node=product) for product in final_qs],
        total_count=query.count(),
        details={
            "header_en": name,
            "header_ar": ar_name,
            "method": kwargs.get("method"),
        },
    )
    connection.page_info = PageInfo(
        start_cursor=start_index,
        end_cursor=(
            int(kwargs.get("first")) + 1
            if int(offset) == 0
            else int(offset) + int(kwargs.get("first"))
        ),
        has_next_page=has_next_page,
        has_previous_page=start_index > 0,
    )
    return connection

Redis Implementation:
seller_lst = obj.get_seller_lst()
redis_obj = RedisUtility()

data = redis_obj.get_products(seller_lst, **kwargs)
if data:
    product_ids = [int(product['id']) for product in data['products']]

    products = Products.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
    connection = ProductsConnection(
        edges=[ProductsConnection.Edge(node=product) for product in products],
        total_count=data['total_count'],
        details={
            "header_en": "name",
            "header_ar": "ar_name",
            "method": kwargs.get("method"),
        },
    )
    connection.page_info = relay.PageInfo(
        start_cursor=str(data['offset']),
        end_cursor=str(
            int(kwargs.get("first")) + 1
            if int(data['offset']) == 0
            else int(data['offset']) + int(kwargs.get("first"))
        ),
        has_next_page=data['end_index'] < data['total_count'],
        has_previous_page=data['offset'] > 0,
    )

    return connection

Redis Utility:
class RedisUtility:
    def __init__(
        self,
        host=settings.REDIS_STACK_HOST,
        port=settings.REDIS_STACK_PORT,
        username=settings.REDIS_STACK_USERNAME,
        password=settings.REDIS_STACK_PASSWORD,
        decode_responses=settings.REDIS_STACK_DECODE_RESPONSES,
    ):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.decode_responses = decode_responses
        self.connection = None

    def connect(self):
        if not self.connection:
            self.connection = get_redis_connection(
                host=self.host,
                port=self.port,
                username=self.username,
                password=self.password,
                decode_responses=self.decode_responses,
            )
        return self.connection

    def get_products(self, seller_lst, **kwargs):
        r = self.connect()

        offset = kwargs.get("after") if kwargs.get("after") else 0
        limit = int(kwargs.get("first", 10))
        category_ids = self.get_category_ids(kwargs.get('slug'), kwargs.get('level'))
        
        category_query = f"@category:{{{' | '.join(map(str, category_ids))}}}"
        seller_query = f"@stock_available_seller:{{{' | '.join(map(str, seller_lst))}}}"
        final_query = f"({category_query}) (@stock_available_seller:({seller_query}))"
        count_query = Query(final_query)
        total_count = r.ft(':product:index').search(count_query).total

        q = Query(final_query).paging(offset, limit)
        result = r.ft(':product:index').search(q)
        
        products = [json.loads(doc.json) for doc in result.docs]
        
        return {
            'total_count': total_count,
            'offset': offset,
            'end_index': offset + limit,
            'products': products
        }

Issue:
Despite implementing Redis, the API is slower compared to fetching data directly from the database. I expected Redis to speed up the process, but it's doing the opposite.
Questions:

What could be the reasons for the slower performance when using Redis?
How can I optimize the Redis implementation to improve the response time?
Are there any best practices for using Redis with Django/GraphQL to ensure better performance?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


Redis will only speed up if (a) the cache can be used, so you fetch the same queue, and (b) (de)serializing is done very efficiently. Your get_by_seller_and_slug here seems to make two queries? Why not store the total number of items directly in the blob, so the second request to the redis.

Actually, I am syncing my database with Redis Stack frequently. The total number is based on the query result and may vary according to the query.

but you use r.ft(':product:index').search(q) and r.ft(':product:index').search(count_query).total, so two queries to redis. This means two round trips, and often the main reason connections are slow is because the thing waits until the redis/database reacts.

r.ft(':product:index').search(q) this one is paginated result. so i wont get the total count of the record.are you suggesting that this two execution is causing the issue??

well that is hard to tell, what if you try to only retrieve the paginated result to test this, so temporary omit the first query.

i tried that, but can't see a big different still its higher than db query
